# How to traverse all the elements in a set?

Tags: set, dolphindb

I performed the set operation (i.e., return the union of two sets minus the intersection of the two sets) on two sets t1 and t2. The result is still a set. I used the following script to iterate over all the elements in the result, but an error is raised. Where is the problem?

```
t1 = set(1..23)
t2 = set(2..34)
result = t1^t2
for(i in result){
    print(i)
}
```

Error message:

```
result => set doesn't support random access.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set is a collection of unique elements and does not support iteration. Convert the set to a vector with `keys()` before you proceed:

```
t1 = set(1..23)
t2 = set(2..34)
result = t1^t2

vecResult = result.keys()

print(vecResult);
[24,25,26,27,28,29,1,30,31,32,33,34]
```